# Getting webpage text

Tags: java, selenium, web

So I'm using Selenium for java and am trying to grab some text from a website after connecting to it. I know selenium has

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

But if there are variables it will return the variables and not the actual data, for example if the actual text I want is

> 13-11-28

What it actually is in the source is

> */month*

or something like that. How can I get the actual text using selenium or another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the element and the perform 'getText' on it.

Example

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".month").getText())
```